# jQuery return parent id from touchwipe

Tags: jquery

I am currently using a plugin called touchwipe.js so that I can swipe left and right to replace the prev and next buttons I have on my custom slider. The only issue I am having is that I can't seem to get the parent id of the gallery I am sliding.

```
$(".gallery").touchwipe({
   wipeLeft: function() {
      var section=$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
      ...
```

When I use just a normal jquery click it works fine. Can you please advise me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and get the parent outside of the touchwipe function, then use it inside it:

```
var gallery = $(".gallery");
var parent  = gallery.parent()..... 

gallery.touchwipe({
   wipeLeft: function() {

      ...
```